# Show "Add more items" for fields of limited cardinality?

Tags: 8, entities

Is there a way to modify the behavior of a field that has limited input to do the 'add more items' button *instead* of show X fields on the screen?

For instance, I have added a link field, that can have up to 5 link values. When it is displayed on the form, it shows 5 empty link fields, instead of one with the option to add more. This display is cumbersome, and makes users believe they must fill all of the fields in, and conversely, become unsure how to 'remove' a link since clearing the field value is less intuitive than clicking 'Remove' that some other fields have.

For UX/training purposes, I would like for fields on forms to behave consistently for limited or unlimited. Has anyone accomplished this behavior using the Form API?

Comment: Is this a Form API specific question?

Comment: My advice would be to configure it as unlimited cardinality (value -1) and use jQuery to disable the "Add another item" button after 4 clicks. I'm no jQuery hero though so maybe you can update your question with this specific information and ask for some jQuery help.

Comment: I have a similar problem and think https://www.drupal.org/project/limited_field_widgets addresses it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a form alter:

```
     YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

        if ($form_id == 'YOURFORM') {
           if (isset($form['YOURFILED']['und']['#max_delta']) && $form['YOURFIELD']['und']['#max_delta'] == 4) {
                $form['YOURFIELD']['und']['add_more']['#prefix'] = '<div style="display:none;">';
                $form['YOURFIELD']['und']['add_more']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
            }
}
```

The max delta should be one less than you want as the maximum. When the delta is 4, then after five addmore fields, the add more button will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8 the above solution does not work.
How I achieved this by setting the field configuration from a limit to "unlimited" (cardinality: -1) and with a customs module form alter to manage the field limit

Example:
In your example.module

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * @param array $form
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 * @param $form_id
 */
function example_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $limit = 100;

  if ($form_id === 'node_xyz_edit_form') {
    if (isset($form['field_abc']['widget']['#max_delta']) && $form['field_abc']['widget']['#max_delta'] >= $limit) {
      unset($form['field_abc']['widget']['add_more']);
    }
  }
}
```

Where  'example' will be your module name,  'node_xyz_edit_form' will be your node form id and 'field_abc' will be the content-type field.

Comment: Works perfect and is better solution than the display:none approach in other answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue on drupal.org describing this problem with a patch to fix it. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1156338